# Listar arquivos de uma pasta específica

Tags: java, android

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
public static final String PATH ="/Conceitos";
    public  static List<String> loadFilesName() throws IOException{
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(0);
        File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath()+PATH);
        if(!dir.exists()){
            dir.mkdirs();
            return strings;
        }
        if(dir.isDirectory()){
            for(final File f :  dir.listFiles()){
                strings.add(f.getName());
            }
        }
        return strings;
    }
```

A pasta já está criada, e possui um arquivo, mas quando tento acessar a lista (`dir.listFiles()`) me retorna o seguinte erro:

> W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of
>   null array

Já adicionei as permissões!

Como faço para listar os arquivos de uma pasta?

Comment: Concedeu permissão [~RunTime](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html) de leitura ou só no Manifest??

Comment: Qual valor está na sua variável PATH?

Comment: Adicionei o **PATH** lá!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Além de conceder permissão no `AndroidManifest.xml`, a partir do Android 6.0 (nível de API 23), os usuários concedem permissões a aplicativos enquanto eles estão em execução, não quando eles são instalados.

Podes criar um método estático, como por exemplo `permissReadFile()` passando por parâmetro o seu contexto. Veja abaixo:

```
public static final int CHECK_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_FILES = 61;
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public static boolean permissReadFile(Activity activity){
    boolean res = true;
    if (activity.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        }

        activity.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                CHECK_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_FILES);
        res = false;
    }
    return res;
}
```

E usa-lo em qualquer parte do seu projeto assim:

```
if (CheckPermission.permissReadFile(this)) {
     // se entrar aqui é porque já concedeu permissão de leitura
}
```

Veja mais [detalhes na documentação](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=pt-br).